# web based document view solution?

Tags: cad, 3d-modelling

Is anyone aware of a web based file view solution? 
Specifically, I'm looking for a solution that i could view CAD、3D Model（most of them are made by intergraph/bently/aveva 3D model software） via Internet browser.
I found Oracle Autovue, and Aveva VNet.
Anyone have any recommendations? 
thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for an existing application, or one you can integrate into your own software?

Comment: Yes,I'm working on a enterprise project,we need to view multiple format documents online.So I need a existing solution,which support me to customize it and integrate into a website.

Answer (score 0):

If plugins (flash, java, 3rd party) are not authorized in your definition of "web based", there is nothing that could allow you to view 3D CAD models on the web. Maybe with the rise of WebGL something will emerge.

Otherwise, if plugins are a possible solution, maybe have a look directly at products and technologies of CAD software editors. For example, Dassault Systemes is promoting the 3DVia plugin to view documents from the CATIA ecosystem, and Siemens PLM is promoting JT as a file format for CAD visualization.

Be warned that these solutions may have strong commercial limitations, and/or "locked" towards the respective ecosystem/PLM of their vendors.